# Print list to an array but always print 1 more item in the list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list

```
p = [10, 4, 18, 3]
```

and I want the output to be `10 10 4 10 4 18 10 4 18 3`

Right now I have

```
pe = []
counter = 0
temp = 0
while counter<=4: 
    for i in range(0,len(p)-temp+1):
        pe.append(p[i])

    temp+=1
    counter+=1
```

but for some reason it only prints 10 and the while loop doesnt go through the for statement again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list slicing:

```
p = [10, 4, 18, 3]

for i in range(1, len(p)+1):
    print(*p[:i], end=' ')
```

Prints:

```
10 10 4 10 4 18 10 4 18 3
```

---

EDIT: To put the values into a list:

```
p = [10, 4, 18, 3]

out = []
for i in range(1, len(p)+1):
    out.extend( p[:i] )

# print the output
for value in out:
    print(value, end=' ')
```

Comment: That does the trick! I am trying to understand why this works but Im really confused. So I understand that slicing is when u take a piece of the list by using colons but how does this go back through the list once it is sliced once?

Comment: @equ1nox Each iteration of the for loop you take larger slice from the list `p`. First iteration `p[:1]`, second iteration `p[:2]` and so on. `p[:1]` returns `[10]`, `p[:2]` returns `[10, 4]` ...

Comment: Ohhh ok I see now. Thanks!!

Comment: Last thing, I want to put this into its own list. I have tried using list() , .append() but I am not getting the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

this  in python 3:

```
p = [10, 4, 18, 3]
q= []
g=[]
for i in range(len(p)+1):
    q = p[0:i]
    g=g+q
str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in g)
print(str1)
```

output

```
10 10 4 10 4 18 10 4 18 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```py
p = [10, 4, 18, 3]

length = len(p)
for i in range(length):
  for j in p[:i]:
    p.append(j)

for i in range(length):
  p.append(p.pop(0))

print(p)
```

**Output**

```
[10, 10, 4, 10, 4, 18, 10, 4, 18, 3]
```